# Scraping a page for URLs using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I can scrape the page to the headlines, no problem. The URLs are another story. They are fragments that get appended on the end of the base URL - I understand that...
What do I need to pull the related URLs for storage in format - base_url.scraped_fragment

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import MySQLdb
import re


html = urlopen("http://advances.sciencemag.org/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read().decode('utf-8'),"lxml")
#links = soup.findAll("a","href")
headlines = soup.findAll("div", "highwire-cite-title media__headline__title")
    for headline in headlines:
    text = (headline.get_text())
    print text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there should be a space between the class names:

```
highwire-cite-title media__headline__title
               HERE^
```

Anyway, since you need the links, you should be locating the `a` elements and use `urljoin()` to make absolute URLs:

```
from urlparse import urljoin

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


base_url = "http://advances.sciencemag.org"
response = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

headlines = soup.find_all(class_="highwire-cite-linked-title")
for headline in headlines:
    print(urljoin(base_url, headline["href"]))
```

Prints:

```
http://advances.sciencemag.org/content/2/4/e1600069
http://advances.sciencemag.org/content/2/4/e1501914
http://advances.sciencemag.org/content/2/4/e1501737
...
http://advances.sciencemag.org/content/2/2
http://advances.sciencemag.org/content/2/1
```

Comment: Works perfectly! to follow up if I wanted the URL paired with the headline, for example:

    Van der Waals metal-semiconductor junction: Weak Fermi level pinning enables effective tuning of Schottky barrier, http://advances.sciencemag.org/content/2/4/e1600069

how would that statement look?

Comment: @citramaillo that you can get from the `headline.get_text()`, check it out. Thanks.