# Python 3.7 scraping a page using BeautifulSoup issues with Available code on stack exchange

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have been trying to do webscraping for the a forum (https://forums.bharat-rakshak.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7630) with the stack overflow code given in

[Scraping a page for URLs using Beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36800951/scraping-a-page-for-urls-using-beautifulsoup)

I updated the Urllib2 to Urllib and the urlopen. However, the code still gives error on the metadata loop

```
for html in metaData:
    text = BeautifulSoup(str(html).strip(),'lxml').get_text().encode("utf-8").replace("\n","") # convert the html to text
    authors.append(text.split("Post by:")[1].split(" on ")[0].strip()) # get Post by:
    times.append(text.split(" on ")[1].strip()) # get date
```

The error I get is 
Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
>   TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: you don't need to encode in utf-8 because it's already unicode

Comment: Thanks, when I removed the unicode using the following comment

for html in metaData:                                                                             
    text = BeautifulSoup(str(html).strip()).get_text()# convert the html to text
    authors.append(text.split("Post by:")[1].split(" on ")[0].strip()) # get Post by:             
    times.append(text.split(" on ")[1].strip()) # get date
I get a new error 
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  IndexError: list index out of range